# Sequelize migration converting Sequelize.UUID primary key field to integer autoincrement in MYSQL

Tags: migration, sequelize.js, uuid

I am using sequelize CLI to generate and run db migrations. The issue I am having is the id field set to data type Sequelize.UUID appearing as an autoincrement integer in mysql. Here is my user model and migration:

**User Model**

```
    'use strict';
    module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
      const User = sequelize.define('User', {
        UserName: {type:DataTypes.STRING,unique:true,allowNull:false},
        FirstName:{type: DataTypes.STRING,allowNull:true},
        LastName: {type:DataTypes.STRING,allowNull:true},
        Email: {type:DataTypes.STRING,allowNull:false,unique:true,validate: { isEmail: {msg: "Invalid Email"} }},
        Password: {type:DataTypes.STRING,allowNull:false},
        Avatar: {type:DataTypes.STRING,allowNull:true},

      }, {});
      User.associate = function(models) {

        User.hasMany(models.RoleUser,
            {
                foreignKey:'UserId',
                as:'userroles',
                sourceKey:'id'
            }),

        User.belongsTo(models.Country,
            {
                foreignKey:'CountryId',
                targetKey:'id'
            }),

            User.belongsToMany(models.Role,
                {
            through: 'RoleUser',
            foreignkey:'UserId'

        })


     };
      return User;
    };

**User Migration file:**

'use strict';
const uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4');

module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('Users', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.UUID
        defaultValue:uuidv4()
      },
      UserName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      FirstName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      LastName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      Email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      Password: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      Avatar: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },

      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('Users');
  }
};
```

**AFTER MIGRATION, THE HIS FIELD IS CONVERTED TO INT AUTOINCREMENT IN MYSQL:**

```
id: {
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            type: Sequelize.UUID
            defaultValue:uuidv4()
          },
```

Any pointer as to why this is happening? Please assist. Even the associations seem not to be formed at all as foreign keys are of type Sequelize.UUID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by adding the id field on model with primary key property set to true.

```
 id: {
type:DataTypes.UUID,
allowNull:false,
unique:true,
primaryKey:true
},
```

Its like sequelize will automatically generate id field of type INTEGER AUTOINCREAMENT if the model does not have a field with primary key set to true.